# Prove that $ (a+b) \cos(x) = a-b$, if $ \sin(x) + \tan(x) = \frac{4a\sqrt{ab}}{a^2-b^2},$ $ \tan(x) - \sin(x) = \frac{4a\sqrt{ab}}{a^2-b^2}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Prove that $ (a+b) \cos(x) = a-b$, if $$ \sin(x) + \tan(x) = \frac{4a\sqrt{ab}}{a^2-b^2},$$
$$ \tan(x) - \sin(x) = \frac{4a\sqrt{ab}}{a^2-b^2}.$$
I tried solving it with system, but with no result.

Comment: Same right hand side for both?

Comment: @A.G. I'm don't know, that's all what is written in book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grand_chat has already pointed out that you may want 
$$\tan x-\sin x=\frac{4\color{red}{b}\sqrt{ab}}{a^2-b^2}\tag 1$$
With 
$$\tan x+\sin x=\frac{4a\sqrt{ab}}{a^2-b^2}\tag 2$$
now $(1)+(2)$ gives
$$2\tan x=\frac{4(a+b)\sqrt{ab}}{(a+b)(a-b)}\Rightarrow \tan x=\frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{a-b}$$
Also, $(2)-(1)$ gives
$$2\sin x=\frac{4(a-b)\sqrt{ab}}{(a-b)(a+b)}\Rightarrow \sin x=\frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{a+b}$$
Here, use
$$\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\Rightarrow \cos x=\frac{\sin x}{\tan x}=\left(\frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{a+b}\right)/\left(\frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{a-b}\right)=\frac{a-b}{a+b}.$$

Answer (score 3):

As written, the solution to the system of equations is $\sin x = 0$. I think you want 
$$\tan x -\sin x={4b\sqrt{ab}\over a^2-b^2}.$$ Then solving the system of equations yields
$$\sin x =\frac12 \left({4a\sqrt{ab}\over a^2-b^2}-{4b\sqrt{ab}\over a^2-b^2}\right)={2\sqrt{ab}\over a+b},$$
which gives $$\cos^2 x = 1 -\sin^2 x = {(a-b)^2\over(a+b)^2}.$$